# Join RDDs based on keys in Pyspark

Tags: join, pyspark, rdd

I have a textfile as shown below:

OrderId|OrderItem|OrderDate|OrderPrice|ItemQuantity
1|Gas|2018-01-17|1895|1
1|Air Conditioners|2018-01-28|19000|3
1|Gas|2018-01-17|2300|1
1|Television|2018-01-11|45000|2
2|Gas|2018-01-17|1895|1
2|Air Conditioners|2017-01-28|19000|3
2|Gas|2016-01-17|2300|1
1|Bottle&&|2018-03-24|45|10
1|Cooking oil|2018-04-22|100|3
3|Inverter|2015-11-02|29000|1
3|Gas|2014-01-09|2300|1
3|Television|2018-01-17|45000|2
1|Gas|2011-01-27|1895|1
1|Air Conditioners|2018-01-28|19000|3
4|Gas|2018-01-17|2300|1
4|Television$$|2018-01-17|45000|2
5|Medicine|2016-03-14|23.50|8
5|Cough Syrup|2016-01-28|190|1
5|Ice Cream|2014-09-23|300|7
5|Pasta|2015-06-30|65|2

```
textdata = sc.textFile("/user/OrderInputFile")
header=textdata.first();
textnewdata = textdata.filter(lambda x:x != header)
splittextdataRDD= textnewdata.map(lambda x: x.split('|'))


filtersplittextdataRDD1 = splittextdataRDD.filter(lambda x : x[0]=='1' or x[0]=='4')
filtersplittextdataRDD2 = splittextdataRDD.filter(lambda x : x[0]=='2' or x[0]=='4')

#creating pair RDDS using key on first position:
pairfiltersplittextdataRDD1 = filtersplittextdataRDD1.map(lambda x :(x[0],x[1:]))
pairfiltersplittextdataRDD2 = filtersplittextdataRDD2.map(lambda x :(x[0],x[1:]))

I am facing issues while joining RDDs on keys
pairjoinRDD = filtersplittextdataRDD1.join(filtersplittextdataRDD2).map(lambda(x[0],(x1,x2)):x1+x2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to join my RDDs. below is the solution:

```
pairjoinRDD = filtersplittextdataRDD1.map(lambda x:(x[0],x)).join(filtersplittextdataRDD2.map(lambda x:(x[0],x )))
```

here is the output:

```
>>> newRdd.take(20);
[(u'4', ([u'4', u'Gas', u'2018-01-17', u'2300', u'1'], [u'4', u'Gas', u'2018-01-17', u'2300', u'1'])), (u'4', ([u'4', u'Gas', u'2018-01-17', u'2300', u'1'], [u'4', u'Television', u'2018-01-17', u'45000', u'2'])), (u'4', ([u'4', u'Television', u'2018-01-17', u'45000', u'2'], [u'4', u'Gas', u'2018-01-17', u'2300', u'1'])), (u'4', ([u'4', u'Television', u'2018-01-17', u'45000', u'2'], [u'4', u'Television', u'2018-01-17', u'45000', u'2']))]
```